# WCF response leaving out <xml header>

Tags: wcf, rest

I am finally starting to get somewhere with WCF, but I have run into another problem. The response sent back does not include the header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

**My Service Contract**

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        // you can have optional parameters by simply specifying them and they will return null if there is nothing in there
        [WebGet(UriTemplate="testing={value}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        [OperationContract]
        XElement GetData(string value);
    }


 [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public XElement GetData(string value)
        {
            return new XElement("Somename", value); 
        }
   }
```

returns this (3 is the value specified)

```
<Somename>3</Somename>
```

Is it also possible to easily wrap a response in a root element? Something like `<response></response>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

responsThe result of calling the GetData method is the contents of what you return in the method. If you want a wrapper then return something like:

```
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public XElement GetData(string value)
    {
        return new XElement("response",
                       new XElement("Somename", value));
    }
}
```

EDIT:

To add the XML declaration (which actually may not be a good idea but you know best) do something like this:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("response",
                           new XElement("Somename", value)));

doc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "true");

return doc.Root;
```

Comment: I thought it was good practice to return the xml declaration, but I honestly don't know.

Comment: The second one doesn't work for me. When I enter the parameter nothing is returned

Comment: I advised caution because the result will be embedded in an HTTP response to be deserialized by a client somewhere. It's the deserialization process (if any) that could have problems with the XML declaration. I'd leave it out unless you have a real reason to need it.

Comment: I added reference to the Root property in the example to fix the issue.

Comment: It still doesn't add it to the output for some reason.

Comment: Please try it after commenting out the line that sets the Declaration. It may that it is the Declaration that is causing the problem. If it is then I'll update my answer to remove that code. Thanks!

Comment: How would we do this when using MessageContracts?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this myself, and stumbled upon this article:

http://shevaspace.blogspot.com/2009/01/include-xml-declaration-in-wcf-restful.html

It solved the problem in my situation, perhaps it is of help for others as well. It describes a custom attribute `IncludeXmlDeclaration` that you can stick on your method, and it will output the xml header.

For completeness, here is the code copied from the article:

```cs
public class XmlDeclarationMessage : Message
{
    private Message message;
    public XmlDeclarationMessage(Message message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public override MessageHeaders Headers
    {
        get { return message.Headers; }
    }

    protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
        // WCF XML serialization doesn't support emitting XML DOCTYPE, you need to roll up your own here.
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        message.WriteBodyContents(writer);
    }


    public override MessageProperties Properties
    {
        get { return message.Properties; }
    }

    public override MessageVersion Version
    {
        get { return message.Version; }
    }
}

public class XmlDeclarationMessageFormatter : IDispatchMessageFormatter
{
    private IDispatchMessageFormatter formatter;
    public XmlDeclarationMessageFormatter(IDispatchMessageFormatter formatter)
    {
        this.formatter = formatter;
    }

    public void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters)
    {
        formatter.DeserializeRequest(message, parameters);
    }

    public Message SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, Object[] parameters, Object result)
    {
        var message = formatter.SerializeReply(messageVersion, parameters, result);
        return new XmlDeclarationMessage(message);
    }
}

public class IncludeXmlDeclarationAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.Formatter = new XmlDeclarationMessageFormatter(dispatchOperation.Formatter);
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
    }
}
```